# Vue.Js - How to parse integer array object data

Tags: arrays, parsing, vuejs2, integer

I've a response data in array object

here my response code :

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 7,
      "product_name": "iPad",
      "rating": "4.00"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "product_name": "iPhone",
      "rating": "3.00"
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "product_name": "iPod",
      "rating": "7.00"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "product_name": "iMac",
      "rating": "9.00"
    }
  ],
  "status": 200,
  "error": 0
}
```

and then i try to map the array object to parse the data 'rating' to integer, here my axios code :

```
getCustomerType: function(store) {
  this.loading = true
  let headers = {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + window.accessToken
  }

  axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: baseApi(this.selectedStore.url_id, 'en', 'customertype'),
    params: this.params,
    headers: headers
  })
    .then(response => {
      this.customerTypeData = response.data.data
      for (let index = 0; index < this.customerTypeData.length; index++) {
        this.customerTypeData.rating[index] = parseInt(this.customerTypeData.rating[index])
      }
      this.loading = false
    })
}
```

But the code of parseInt it doesn't make it solve

```
for (let index = 0; index < this.customerTypeData.length; index++) {
        this.customerTypeData.rating[index] = parseInt(this.customerTypeData.rating[index])
      }
```

**Expected** :

rating (by index) it change from string to number by index array

Comment: According with your JSON response you should access rating this way: `this.customerTypeData[index].rating = parseInt(this.customerTypeData[index].index)`

Comment: `this.customerTypeData.rating[index]` should be `this.customerTypeData[index].rating`? Your response object suggests the latter.

Comment: oh great, thanks @ricardoorellana